# why can't I fetch sql statements in python?

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I have a very large table (374870 rows) and when I run the following code timestamps just ends up being a long int with the value 374870.... I want to be able to grab all the timestamps in the table... but all I get is a long int :S

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(
                host    = "Some Host",
                user    = "SOME USER",
                passwd  = "SOME PASS",
                db      = "SOME DB",
                port    = 3306

        )

sql = "SELECT `timestamp` from `table`"

timestamps = db.cursor().execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
timestamps = []
for rec in cur:
    timestamps.append(rec[0])
```

Comment: This solutions works, Thanks eumiro. still a bit annoyed that fetchall() doesn't work.

Comment: you can change my fourth line into `for rec in cur.fetchall():` and it will work too

Comment: arg, Brain gone to mush. that is what I was screwing up. fetch functions belong to cursor object :S

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `fetchmany()` on the cursor to fetch more than one row, or call `fetchone()` in a loop until it returns `None`.

Comment: the problem is that timestamps ends up being a long int... Maybe due to the large size of my table. so fetchone() fetchmany() or fetchall() will not work for timestamps because a long int object does not have those functions...

Comment: @Richard, 374870 is not really a large table. Try my answer and you will see that the list `timestamps` can accomodate your data. If you tell me what it now looks like, we can try to convert it to any format you need.

Comment: @Richard: fetchone and friends are **cursor** methods. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possibility that the not-very-long integer that you are getting is the number of rows in your query result.

Consider reading the docs ([PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)) ... (1) return value from cursor.execute() is not defined; what you are seeing is particular to your database and for portability sake should not be relied on. (2) you need to do `results = cursor.fetch{one|many|all}()` or iterate over the cursor ... `for row in cursor: do_something(row)`